# AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, linux, ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic app on my Linux box and when I run `$ ionic run android` it gets to `:processDebugResources` on the build process before it errors out with the message

```
App/platforms/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:43:23-37 : AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon')

Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I am able to test most functionality via a web browser, but I've gotten to the point in the project where I need to test functionality on an actual device.

Comment: Well it appears that you don't have an icon.png or similar in your res/drawable folder?

Comment: @GONeale that file was auto-generated when I added Android to my project. I've tired changing the value, but when I try run the deploy command it overwrites it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `ionic resources` and it will create the resources directory and add the icons.

Comment: That might be the answer but, write a description & explain why it is so.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem with custom plugin that was using some resources. In my case problem was fixed by adding resource files directly to platform (on Android it was content from plugin `/res` directory, copied to `platforms/android/res`).